# If $I_n = \int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^n dx$ then what is $\frac{I_4}{I_3}$ and $\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $I_n = \int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^n dx$ then what is $\frac{I_4}{I_3}$ and $\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}$?
I tried to use integration by parts but, it still doesn't work out. Can someone tell me the simplest way to find $\frac{I_4}{I_3}$ and $\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}$ because using the conventional method it's taking a long time?
I know that $\frac{I_4}{I_3} \sim 7.3846$, but as I said before it took a lot of time.

Comment: $\frac{I_4}{I_3} =\frac{96}{13}$ using my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
I_{n+1} &=& \int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^{n+1} dx\\
&=&x(8-x^3)^{n+1}\bigg|_0^2+(n+1)\int_{0}^{2}x(8-x^3)^{n}3x^2 dx\\
&=&3(n+1)\int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^{n}x^3 dx\\
&=&-3(n+1)\int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^{n}[(8-x^3)-8] dx\\
&=&-3(n+1)\int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^{n+1}dx+24(n+1)\int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^{n}dx\\
&=&-3(n+1)I_{n+1}+24(n+1)I_n
\end{eqnarray}
and from this, it is easy to get $I_{n+1}/I_n$. I omit the detail.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$I_n = \int_{0}^{2}(8-x^3)^n \,dx=2^{3 n+1}\int_0^1 \left(1-t^3\right)^n\,dt=$$

Now
$$t^3=u \implies \int_0^1 \left(1-t^3\right)^n\,dt=\frac 13\int_0^1 { u^{-\frac 23}}{(1-u)^n}\,du=\frac 13B\left(\frac{1}{3},n+1\right)$$ Using the gamma function equivalent

$$I_n=\frac{2^{3 n+1}} 3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\frac{ \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Generalization**: $$\dfrac{d(x(a+bx^r)^n)}{dx}$$

$$=(a+bx^r)^n+n(a+bx^r)^{n-1}rbx^r$$

$$=(a+bx^r)^n+rn(a+bx^r)^{n-1}(a+bx^r-a)$$

$$=(a+bx^r)^n(1+rn)-arn(a+bx^r)^{n-1}$$

Integrating both wrt $x,$   $$x(a+bx^r)^n=(1+rn)I_n-arnI_{n-1}$$ where $\displaystyle I_n=\int(a+bx^r)^n\ dx$

Can you recognize $a,b,r$ here?